# Mapping elastic beanstalk (wordpress blog) to subdomain

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

So I have set up my static website via S3 and have attached it to my domain example.com.

Then, I have launched a separate wordpress blog via Elastic Beanstalk, let's say exampleblog.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com.

I have already configured my CNAME settings in Route 53 such that blog.example.com maps to my elastic beanstalk site (exampleblog.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com), except, once I start clicking around on the blog itself, the URLs all become exampleblog.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/NAME-OF-PAGE

How do I get a complete subdomain redirect? i.e., I want all of the pages in my blog to be in the form blog.example.com/NAME-OF-PAGE

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay -- I have actually figured this out myself so just will share in case anyone else has the same question:

It's really simple - You just need to access Wordpress > Settings > General and then update your site address (URL) to your subdomain (in my case, blog.example.com).

Boom!